# Is it possible to link to a shared library without access to the library itself?

Tags: linux, linker, shared-libraries, ld, elf

I have the header files of a shared library but not the shared library nor its source code.

Can I still compile some code against this library?

If not, what information does the shared library contain which is not in the headers?

Comment: It is possible in AIX: when linking, you can use an _export-file_ instead of the actual library. I don't know if something like that is possible in GNU/Linux

Comment: See also: [c++ - Do shared libraries (.so) files need to present (or specified) at link time? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42017681/do-shared-libraries-so-files-need-to-present-or-specified-at-link-time)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Can I still compile some code against this library?

Compile: yes. Link: maybe.

You can create a dummy library to link against. E.g. if the header contains:

```
int library_func(void*);
```

then:

```
// dummy_lib.c
int library_func(void *p) { return 0; }

gcc -fPIC -shared -o libfoo.so dummy_lib.c

# Now you can use libfoo.so to link your program.
```

There are some gotcha's:

1. The real library may have `SONAME` of something other than `libfoo.so` (e.g. `libfoo.so.2`). There is no way for you to know without access to the real `libfoo`.
2. The real library could use versioned symbols. If you link your program against the dummy library, it will use default version of all referenced symbols, which is likely to be correct now, but is likely to break in the future (if/when the real library is updated with a new and *incompatible* implementation of any symbols you call).

Comment: I found a simpler although less robust solution: Create an empty library using clang: `echo "" | clang++ -shared -fPIC -x c++ - -o libfoo.so` and tell `clang / ld` to ignore the unresolved symbols when linking: `-Wl,--unresolved-symbols=ignore-in-object-files`.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. You can declare pointers-to-functions for them, and then call `dlopen` and `dlsym`, and off you go. However, trying to concoct somehow an executable or shared library which acts as if you've linked to the library is risky; see Employed Russian's answer for details.

You will need this libraries themselves to *run* the code, of course.

However, note that not all 'shared libs' are just shared libs. In some cases, there is a `.a` file that is used at link time to supply some statically linked code in addition to the `.so` at runtime. This is not common.

Comment: "The linker does not change anything based on the contents of the libraries." -- this is very much false when one considers versioned symbols.

Comment: I don't think that versioned symbols have curious effects of this form when you are going to use dlopen and dlsym. I will clarify.

Comment: `dlsym` and versioned symbols interact in even more confusing (arguably broken) ways. https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=14932

Answer (score 2):

For those who just want it done, aside from using a dummy lib, there is another (probably **even less robust**) option: `patchelf`

Execute the following command after linking complete

```bash
patchelf --add-needed missinglib.so mylib.so
```

For CMake users, this can be done automatically by adding

```
add_custom_command(
    TARGET mylib POST_BUILD
    COMMAND patchelf --add-needed missinglib.so "$<TARGET_FILE:mylib>")
```