# Program to a library that I don't have with Fortran

Tags: dll, fortran, dylib

I'd like to build a Fortran program that will use a library with a specific interface, but I don't have the library currently installed on my system. I only need to compile the Fortran program, not run it. I assume that the system where my program is run will have the library installed in a standard location (i.e. `/usr/lib`).

Is this possible?

Specifically, I'd like to use the Conda-build system to compile a program that links to the MATLAB library (libmex). Since MATLAB is not installable with Conda or other package managers, I was hoping I could somehow build my program in such a way that it has the correct function call to libmex but requiring that users will have libmex installed in a place where my program can find it.

Comment: No, it won't work.

Comment: If you know both the install path of the library and what symbols it exports, you can simply write a C file that defines all those functions with stub implementations, compile that into a library, and link against it.

Comment: You may be able to _compile_ but you'll have a harder time _linking_. Even compiling may be impossible, such as if you need (Fortran) modules, etc., provided by the library implementation. Please give more details of your requirements.

Comment: @francescalus yes the linking part is what I think I'm missing. I've added specific details to the question.

Comment: Is it true that in C/C++, you can do this with a header file? Though that doesn't take care of the linking problem. My understanding of "dynamic linking" is that the program can search a list of locations at runtime for a required library.

Comment: @raf It can, but you still have to persuade the linker to link the program for you and I do not think it is possible without actually having the library.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45014588/is-it-possible-to-link-to-a-shared-library-without-access-to-the-library-itself See also the comment by Georg Schölly

Comment: Thanks @VladimirF. Sounds like its possible though painful and possibly error prone.